# ActionView::Template::Error Upgraded from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.2.11.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, requirejs, asset-pipeline

I have recently upgraded the application from Rails 4.0 to Rails Rails 4.2.11.3 All Assets precompiled successfully and at only place I am getting the ActionView::Template::Error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (folders.js):
15:     = stylesheet_link_tag 'upload_manager'
16:     = stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery.dialog2'
17:     = yield(:css)
18:     = requirejs_include_tag('folders').gsub('/assets/folders','folders').html_safe
19:     = csrf_meta_tags
20:     = yield(:head)
21:     = render 'layouts/google_analytics'
app/views/layouts/folders.html.haml:18:in 
`_app_views_layouts_folders_html_haml___508411910895359596_47383496907100'
app/controllers/folders_controller.rb:104:in `edit'
```

Strange thing is this issue is not occurring in my local machine, This only occurs in my Stage environment.